# Execute java compiled class command line

Tags: java, command-line, cp, scjp

I have the following question. Given a correctly compiled class whose source code is:

```
1. package com.sun.sjcp;
2.
3. public class Commander {
4.     public static void main(String[] args) {
5.         // more code here
6.     }
7. }
```

Assume that the class file is located in `/foo/com/sun/sjcp/`, the current directory is `/foo/`, and that the classpath contains "." (current directory). Which command line correctly runs Commander?

```
A. java Commander
B. java com.sun.sjcp.Commander
C. java com/sun/sjcp/Commander
D. java -cp com.sun.sjcp Commander
E. java -cp com/sun/sjcp Commander
```

Answer: B

> A. We are in the root dir, so we can't see the file from
>   /foo/com/sun/sjcp/ directly
>
> B. is correct
>
> **C. I think is correct too ???**
>
> D. We are in /foo/com/sun/sjcp/ and there is only class file with
>   package *package com.sun.sjcp;* so the compiler can't find it.
>   If the file was without package declaration and was build in this dir
>   then it will work if we try to run it in this way.
>
> E. The same as D - does not work

The only answer given is B. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is incorrect because "com/sun/sjcp/Commander" isn't a valid class name. Path to a file and class name are not the same things.

(edited): It's appeared "that the jvm allows you to use a forward slash in place of a dot in the fully qualified name of the class to run" (but you must use only **forward slashes**). So it seems that **C** is also correct

Comment: I try to execute java com/sun/sjcp/Commander from  foo and it works? In scjp I have Commander.class file. I am confused

Comment: @Xelian, you are right, I got the same result as you. It seems that C is also correct. "The jvm allows you to use a forward slash in place of a dot in the fully qualified name of the class to run" - I found only this tip on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

A class name can never have forward slashes on it (it's not the same concept as a filesystem path), that's why B is the only right answer.